# ASP.Net ITemplate - how do i read the raw content defined inside

Tags: asp.net, itemplate

i have situation where in i would like to read the content of the ITemplate.

for example i have something like

```
<WD:PopUpPanel runat="server" ID="MyPoPUp">
<InitScript>
    // javascript
    document.getElementByID('urName').value = 'enter your name';
</InitScript>
<Content>
    Name:<asp:TextBox runat="Server" ID="urName"/>
</Content>
</WD:PopUpPanel>
```

basically the contents inside the `InitScript` is some javascript, which i want to use in `ScriptManager.RegisterScript`.

so my question is how do i define InitScript???

i tried

```
public ITemplate InitScript;
```

this gives me `CompiledTemplateBuilder` object, how do i read the content inside `InitScript` ???

thanks for reading, any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to instantiate your template into a template container control.

Below is an example of doing this - a user control with `InitScript` property; this template is being instantiated in the control's `OnPreRender` method. After this you could just add this template control to the user control child control collection or, as you asked in your question, render it as a string (I use my `RenderControl` utility method to render control as a string):

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate InitScript { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InitScript != null)
        {
            Control templateContainer = new Control();
            InitScript.InstantiateIn(templateContainer);
            //Controls.Add(templateContainer);

            // here is "a raw" content of your template
            var s = RenderControl(templateContainer);
        }
    }

    private string RenderControl(Control control)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
            {
                control.RenderControl(textWriter);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd still have to add template to the control collection. Otherwise it will bypass page lifecycle and you will have template controls "reseting" on every postback. I usually build my controls in the CreateChildControls override, and attach all templates there.

Comment: @Sergei, yes you're right. The code above is just a *quick* example, the main purpose of it is to show how to render a control as a string. Thanks for your comment anyway.